# Monitoring of cron jobs in crontab using shell script

Tags: shell-script, cron, logs

Could someone help in writing a shell script to monitor different cron jobs in crontab. As everyone knows different cron jobs run at different time I want to capture following things in **".csv"** format:

1. Script Name
2. Scheduled times
3. Next scheduled time
4. Last Run time.
5. Did the script ended successfully or it had an error after executing (Success/Fail).

I have certain limitations:

1. `syslog` is not printing all the debug logs.
2. Can't edit **crontab**.

I have logs which are directed which could be used.

Comment: Unless you have root access this is next to impossible because the necessary information is not available to non- root users. If you do have root you can edit crontab (technically, if not administratively).

Comment: logs cannot be used???

Comment: cron scheduling syntax is pretty hairy.  what's the difference between 2,3,4

Comment: if Vixie cron use `-L15` on the command-line

Answer (score 0):

Given the criteria you have specified this is not possible.

The necessary information is not available to non- root users. If you do have root you can edit crontab (technically, if not administratively) or change the flags used to run from, or read the cron log files.